# Transfer Function Confidence interval estimation

Tags: sas, prediction, transfer-function

I've obtained a Transfer Function model to predict the value of $y_t$ which is:

$$ y_t - \mu = \frac{0.0034 + 0.0024B^9}{1- 0.9B}x_{t-9} + \frac{1}{1+0.6B} a_t 
$$

I obtained this model with SAS, and each parameter is estimated as a T-Student distribution and the standard deviation for each parameter also is available. 
The $x_t$ is the input parameter and $a_t$ is the white noise.

I obtained predictions of $y_t$ with assigned values for different scenarios. Also, I need the confidence interval for the predicted values, but I do not know how I can calculated them.
Please guide me how I can calculate them according to the obtained formula or with SAS commands.

Thanks,
Afshin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am reading this correctly, you have created a time-series model to predict [image] using transfer functions on external inputs, but would like to get confidence intervals of your predictions.

You can get all of this information by placing your model in `PROC ARIMA` and requesting output:

```
proc arima data=have;
    identify var=y crosscorr=(x1 x2 x3);
    estimate input=( (1)x1 /(2)x2 3$x3);
    forecast lead=12 out=Output_Dataset;
run;
```

Where,

`(1)x1` has a numerator factor of 1

`/(2)x2` has a denominator factor of 2

`3$x3` is backshifted 3 lags

If you had both numerator and denominator factors and also want to backshift 3 lags, you would write, for example, `3$(1)/(2)x3`.

`PROC ARIMA` automatically assumes you are using conditional least squares estimation. If you want to use maximum likelihood estimation, specify `method=ML` in the `estimate` statement.

You can specify the alpha of your confidence interval using the `alpha=` option in the `forecast` step. Otherwise, it will assume `alpha=0.05`.

The data set `Output_Dataset` will give you confidence intervals, predictions, and more.